A mistake in Wikipedia article about Inner product and Hodge star?
In the Wikipedia article about Exterior Algebra, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Interior_product, it is said that if we note $\sigma$ the volume element of an oriented vector space $V$ with an inner product
$\langle\bullet, \bullet\rangle$, the Hodge star operator can be defined by composing first the isomorphism between $\bigwedge^k V$ and $\bigwedge^k V^*$ induced by the inner product with the isomorphism
$$\bigwedge^k V^*\to\bigwedge^{n-k} V: \alpha\to\iota_\alpha\sigma$$
This means that here the hodge star is define as
$$\bigwedge^k V\to\bigwedge^{n-k} V: v\to\iota_{v^\flat}\sigma=\star v$$
I tried to check this formula with the usual definition of the Hodge star, which is, if $v, w\in\bigwedge^k V$
$$w\wedge\star v=\langle w, v\rangle\ \sigma$$
Using the fact that $\iota_{v^\flat}$ is an anti-derivation, I get that
$$w\wedge \iota_{v^\flat}\sigma=(-1)^{k+1}\iota_{v^\flat}w\wedge\sigma$$
Using the fact that $\iota_{v^\flat}$ is the adjoint of the operator $v\wedge\bullet$ for the inner product, I get that
$$\langle v\wedge \mathbb{1}, w\rangle=\langle\mathbb{1}, \iota_{v^\flat}w\rangle$$ which is exactly
$$\langle v, w\rangle=\iota_{v^\flat}w$$
So I found that
$$\star v=(-1)^{k+1}\iota_{v^\flat}\sigma$$
Did I make a mistake or is the Wikipedia article wrong or did I miss something ?

$\iota_\alpha$ is only an antiderivation when $\alpha$ is a covector. Here that means $k=1$ and we get $\star v =\iota_{v^\flat}\sigma$.

@NicholasTodoroff You are perfectly right. My reasoning was flawed and because of your remark I was able to finish a good demonstration that showed that Wikipedia was ... right!

$
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}
$$\iota_\alpha$ is only an antiderivation when $\alpha$ is a covector. Here that means $k=1$ and we get $\star v =\iota_{v^\flat}\sigma$.
If you want to prove this and you have the adjoint property then all you need to do is the following:
From $\langle\sigma,\sigma\rangle=1$ and the definition of the Hodge star applied to $v=\star^{-1}u$ we get
$$
  \langle\sigma, w\wedge u\rangle = \langle w,\star^{-1}u\rangle \implies (-1)^{k(n-k)}\langle\iota_{u^\flat}\sigma,w \rangle = \langle w,\star^{-1}u\rangle.
$$
Since this is true for all $w$ we get
$$
  (-1)^{k(n-k)}\iota_{u^\flat}\sigma = \star^{-1}u
$$
but $\star^{-1}u = (-1)^{k(n-k)}{\star u}$ so we're done.

Thank you for your efficient efforts. Just two little questions before accepting your answer 1/ it is easy to make your proof work for pseudo metric because in that case $<\sigma, \sigma>$ is the signature right ? 2/ is my proof correct ?

Yes, $\langle\sigma,\sigma\rangle = (-1)^q$ where $q$ is the number of $-$'s in the metric. This also becomes a factor in $\star^{-1}$ and the two cancel out.

Following the correction done by @NicholasTodoroff in his comment, I am now able to finish the demonstration that Wikipedia is actually right.
I suppose $v=v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k$. Then $\iota_{v^\flat}=\iota_{v_k^\flat}\circ\cdots\circ\iota_{v_1^\flat}$. Then using the fact that each factor is an anti-derivation, it is easy to show by induction on $k$ that
$$w\wedge \iota_{v^\flat}\sigma=(-1)^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}\iota_{(v^\flat)^\mathbf{T}}w\wedge\sigma$$
Then I get by the same reasoning than before that
$$\langle v^\mathbf{T}, w\rangle=(-1)^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}\iota_{v^\flat}w$$
and we can conclude that Wikipedia is right and the two definitions of Hodge star coincides.

The induction isn't so obvious to me, and I don't see how the $(-1)^{k(k-1)/2}$ factor and the $(v^\flat)^{\mathbf T}$ would pop up naturally (it seems to me more naturally you would just get $\iota_{v^\flat}w\wedge\sigma$), but this seems like a valid approach for proving this.

@NicholasTodoroff There are actually two ways to do the induction. The one I followed gives the factor and the transpose, the other one gives what is natural for you. Hopefully the two results are equal.
